# Dismissing the keyboard in a UIText Field when a Button is pressed in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4, storyboard, xcode4.2

Creating a login page in xcode 4.2

I have the users fill out information in a textfield.

I have the keyboard appear and I can get it dismiss when the user clicks the done button inside the keyboard.

I want the keyboard to dismiss when the user clicks on a button.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call

```
[self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

in your action method from the button.